# I have an ordered grouped query, how know what is the first field that change over previous register

Tags: sql, oracle

i have a query like this

```
SELECT FIELD_1, FIELD_2... FIELD_N, SUM(AMOUNT) 
FROM TABLE 
GROUP BY FIELD_1, FIELD_2... FIELD_N 
ORDER BY FIELD_1, FIELD_2... FIELD_N
```

Is there any way to know what's the first field that change over the previous register when i process the query results?

I'm searching for an sql function (it's an Oracle Database) like `GROUPING_ID`, but that it's only is useful with `GROUP BY ROLLUP` queries, and i don't want subtotals.

If there is not such function i have to program a manual search, and I want to minimize the access to the result set.

Comment: Your question would be clearer if you provided sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you can do what you want using analytic functions to do what you want.  Perhaps this is what you want?

```
SELECT FIELD_1, FIELD_2... FIELD_N, SUM(AMOUNT),
       (case when field_1 <> lag(field_1) over (order by FIELD_1, FIELD_2... FIELD_N) or
                  lag(field_1) over (order by FIELD_1, FIELD_2... FIELD_N) is null
             then 'field_1'
             when field_2 <> lag(field_2) over (order by FIELD_1, FIELD_2... FIELD_N)
             then 'field_2'
             . . .
             else 'field_n'
        end) as WhichGrouping
FROM TABLE
GROUP BY FIELD_1, FIELD_2... FIELD_N
ORDER BY FIELD_1, FIELD_2... FIELD_N
```

Comment: Exactly what i'm looking for! It makes the query slower, but i think that it will be compensated in its processment